# How to change button content color in windows phone 8.1 App development

Tags: user-interface, button, windows-phone-8.1

Is there any easy way to change the button content font color in XAML? Seems the default color is white.

[image]

For instance, I want to customize the color not the Notebook Title here.

Answer (score 1):

You can set text color in Foreground property

```
<Button Foreground="Red">
```